# How to open a Huge TXT format product catalog (Few GB in size)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database

I have a product catalog in CSV-like format that I Want to view.
First I downloaded it from FTP in .TXT.GZ format, and it is 250MB.
IF I extract it, then it is a TXT file of 3.3 GB.

I've tried my Excel 2010 version 14, but it's so big that it doesn't even try to open it. Access fails as well saying file "too large".

Comment: you  can also try with Access.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "view". For a CSV file, that's not as obvious as one might think. I'd give it a try with `Notepad++` to inspect it and look up a few things but that's probably not satisfactory if you want to work with it.

Comment: Access just told me "file too large". and yes basically I want to filter the catalog so its not only view.

Comment: At a guess, you're hitting 32-bit memory limit. idk for certain but I doubt Office 2010 is 64-bit, even if you're on a 64-bit OS. In practise, about 1.7GB is the limit for a 32-bit app on a 32-bit OS, 3.7GB on a 64-bit OS

Comment: If this must be done in Excel, you could try a 64 bit version of Excel; you could try reading in the file one line at a time and splitting the information over several worksheets (or workbooks if you don't have enough memory).  You might be able to use a 64-bit version of Access, but I do not have experience in that regard.

Comment: How many rows of data does your file contain?

Answer (score 0):

How big is it? Actually "250,000 MB" (so 250GB!) or 250MB?

If it actually is 250GB then I doubt that you can handleit in excel. Instead consider storing the information into something desgined for large data, sunch as a database.

If it is 250MB (or 250.000KB) then excel can probably handle it. However excel is limited to about 1.8 million lines. If it is more you will need to chop the file into parts and load them into individual speadsheets or into tabs.

(I recently did the last with a 120MB file with 2.5mil lines in exccel 2015, though I used various BSD tools to filter the data. The last might not be needed for you. A simple text editor might do).

Comment: Sorry, 250MB when zipped. 3.3GB when unzipped.

Comment: Ugh. That is big. Much bigger than I tested (my test file was 47.433.689 bytes uncompressed)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want to do a simple text editor (NOT default Notepad) such as Notepad++ or Textpad will let you view the file
You can then copy an paste groups of lines (~500k) into an excel sheet.

You may want to use a more powerful machine (>8GB ram) and consider 64-bit office to make full use of it.

I don't know how well a cloud-based tool would handle this (you would definitely need a good link) so you could try using something like Google sheets, load to drive then open.